# Javascript: creating exported classes in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

```
// a.js
function A() {}
A.prototype.foo = function () {};
module.exports.A = A;
// index.js
var A = require ('./a');
new A(); // <- Throws TypeError: A is not a constructor
```

The files are bundled with WebPack with babel loader. Any idea as to why the error is thrown? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I simply had to

```
var A = require ('./a').A;
```